# Can you specify a key for $addToSet in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document:

```
{ 'profile_set' :
  [
    { 'name' : 'nick', 'options' : 0 },
    { 'name' : 'joe',  'options' : 2 },
    { 'name' : 'burt', 'options' : 1 }
  ] 
}
```

and would like to add a new document to the `profile_set` set if the name doesn't already exist (regardless of the option).

So in this example if I tried to add:

`{'name' : 'matt', 'options' : 0}`

it should add it, but adding

`{'name' : 'nick', 'options' : 2}`

should do nothing because a document already exists with name `nick` even though the `option` is different.

Mongo seems to match against the whole element and I end up with to check if it's the same and I end up with

```
profile_set containing [{'name' : 'nick', 'options' : 0}, {'name' : 'nick', 'options' : 2}]
```

Is there a way to do this with `$addToSet` or do I have to push another command?

Comment: Since you cannot guarantee that $addToSet will run first you will need two commands to do this

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can qualify your `update` with a query object that prevents the update if the `name` is already present in `profile_set`.  In the shell:

```js
db.coll.update(
    {_id: id, 'profile_set.name': {$ne: 'nick'}}, 
    {$push: {profile_set: {'name': 'nick', 'options': 2}}})
```

So this will only perform the `$push` for a doc with a matching `_id` and where there isn't a `profile_set` element where `name` is `'nick'`.

Comment: If i later need to change mick's name, that is change an existing array object, not add a new one. Is there a way to do that in one atomic update operation that still honor the unique constraint of name?

Comment: Follow up question regarding **changing** an existing object in profile_set: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590219/change-an-existing-object-in-an-array-but-still-preserve-key-uniqueness.

Comment: Everywhere I went to resolve mongoose or mongo problems, @JohnnyHK always saved me.

Comment: @JohnnyHK what if I need to overwrite the value if it already exist?

Comment: I think this query is not correct.  If there is "nick" and at least one other element, it will return true. for $ne : 'nick'.

Comment: @TimT No, it's good. The way `$ne` works with arrays is that it's only a match if _no_ array elements match the value (not just any element).

Comment: Kindly anyone reply to @Alex question above. What is needed to update the element if its already present else push?

Comment: doesn't seem possible to do an upsert in one operation.

Comment: Is it possible to use this code when adding multiple objects to an array, so checking all of them for that field?

Comment: This work unless you want to replace using a [key,value] pair in the array, which sounds like the usecase described.

Comment: Yeah, this will work. However, if you want to add more values you loose the consistency support between multiple update executions.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 13):

As of MongoDB 4.2  there is a way to do this using [aggregation expressions in update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

For your example case, you would do this:

```
newSubDocs = [ {'name' : 'matt', 'options' : 0}, {'name' : 'nick', 'options' : 2} ];
db.coll.update( { _id:1 },
[ 
   {$set:  { profile_set:  {$concatArrays: [ 
      "$profile_set",  
      {$filter: {
             input:newSubDocs, 
             cond: {$not: {$in: [ "$$this.name", "$profile_set.name" ]}} 
      }}
   ]}}}
])
```

Comment: MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$set' in '0.$set' is not valid for storage.

Comment: Sounds like you didn’t get full syntax correct.  You might want to ask with all the details in community.mongodb.com