# $addToSet works like $push

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to implement quite typical combination of $addToSet and $inc but for some strange reason $addToSet adds multiple records with the same id (works like $push):

```
{ _id: 52ce27691cb76b5a60cc11f7,
  news: 
   [ { _id: 52ce2769c2f35d3d21000018,
       count: 2,
       item: 52ce2769c2f35d3d21000017 },
     { item: 52ce2769c2f35d3d21000017,
       _id: 52ce2769c2f35d3d21000019 } ] }
```

Here is the code:

```
        this.update({ _id : interval._id },
            { $addToSet : { news : { item : item } } },
            function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                    return;
                }

                this.update({ _id : interval._id, 'news.item' : item },
                    { $inc : { 'news.$.count' : 1 } },
                    callback);
            }.bind(this));
```

This code was called two times so two item: 52ce2769c2f35d3d21000017 was created. $inc part works well. `item` and `interval` are mongoose model objects.

Comment: Have you tried executing the update query directly in the mongo shell?

Comment: Wait you are trying to addtoset to a non array `item` field there...are you sure it should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of `$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/): "adds a value to an array only if the value is not in the array already"

But what is "*the value*"? In this case it's the **entire object**, because that's the value that you're trying to add to the array. However, the objects aren't equivalent because the one you've added first already has an increased `count`, while the to-be-added object does not. Hence, they don't have the same value in all fields and MongoDB doesn't regard them as being 'equal'.

Keep in mind that `_id` is not a special field in an embedded array and has no additional semantics.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any method then that adds the value to the array by checking only one property?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so. You can modify the query as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527980/can-you-specify-a-key-for-addtoset-in-mongo, but that calls for a multikey query and might even require a negation, which can be costly. I tend to not use embedded arrays for anything but the most simple operations.