# How to addToSet with date field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have following model in mongoose :

```
var RelationSchema = new Schema({
  user : {type:ObjectId, ref:'users'}
  , type : String
  , remarks : String
  , createdOn : {type:Date, default:Date.now}
}, {_id:false});

var UserRelationSchema = new Schema({
  user : {type:ObjectId, ref:'users'}
  , relations : [RelationSchema]
});

var UserRelation = mongoose.model('user_relations', UserRelationSchema);
```

Each time I run the following command with same values a new sub-document is being added to the `relations` array. If I removed `createdOn` field from the `RelationSchema` schema then it works fine.

```
UserRelation.update(
{"user":<ObjectId>} 
, {
    $addToSet: {
       "relations": {"user":<ObjectId>,"type":<String>}
    }
, {upsert:true}
});
```

My Question is :
**How can I `addToSet` with date/time fields ?**

Answer (score 1):

For `$addToSet` to not add an element, the element must *completely* match an existing element.  With `createdOn` being the current time it's easy to see why that never happens in your case.

So `$addToSet` works fine for elements with `Date` fields, but it requires an exact match, just like with any other type.

Comment: I don't think it is feasible to exact match unless we removed the `Date` field , is there any way to ignore some field while `addToSet` ing .

Comment: that would be a nice feature

Comment: @JohnnyHK Did you find any answer for this? I'm looking for the same

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528282/1259510) for one approach.