# Change an existing object in an array but still preserve key uniqueness

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document:

```js
{ 'profile_set' :
  [
    { 'name' : 'nick', 'options' : 0 },
    { 'name' : 'joe',  'options' : 2 },
    { 'name' : 'burt', 'options' : 1 }
  ] 
}
```

If I want to **add** new object to the `profile_set` **only** if the `name` of the object isn't already taken, regardless of the `options`, I can qualify my `update` with a query object that prevents the update if the `name` is already present in `profile_set`.  In the shell:

```js
db.coll.update(
    {_id: id, 'profile_set.name': {$ne: 'nick'}}, 
    {$push: {profile_set: {'name': 'nick', 'options': 2}}})
```

So this will only perform the `$push` for a doc with a matching `_id` and where there isn't a `profile_set` element where `name` is `'nick'`.

**Question** But if I later need to change Nick's name (and maybe his options too...), that is **change** an existing array object, not add a new one. Is there a way to do that in one atomic update operation that still honor the unique constraint of `name`?

Comment: One suggestion: use addtoset instead of push http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: I think addtoset will deny the update only if the complete object already exist, my wish is to ensure uniqueness on only one key, and not the whole object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two conditions, I think:

```js
var newName = "somename";
var oldName = "nick";
var newOption = 3;

// if not change the name
db.coll.update({
    _id : id,
    'profile_set.name' : oldName
}, {
    $set : {
        "profile_set.$.options" : newOption
    }
});

// if change the name
db.coll.update({
    _id : id,
    $and : [ {
        'profile_set.name' : {
            $ne : newName
        }
    }, {
        'profile_set.name' : oldName    
    } ]
}, {
    $set : {
        "profile_set.$.name" : newName,
        "profile_set.$.options" : newOption

    }
});
```