# Update nested object in MongoDB if it exists, otherwise add it

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've got a json doc like this in mongoDB:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("57ed88c0965bedd2b11d5727"),
   "refid" : 2,
   "votes" : [
     { "ip" : "127.0.2.1", "rating" : 5 },
     { "ip" : "127.0.3.1", "rating" : 2 },
     { "ip" : "127.59.83.210", "rating" : 50 },
     { "ip" : "127.56.26.191", "rating" : 5 },
     { "ip" : "127.59.83.210", "rating" : 5 },
     { "ip" : "127.59.83.210", "rating" : 30 }
    ]
 }
```

And instead of creating dupes per IP, I want to update the record found if the IP exists, or add a new entry if it doesn't. There are tons of questions on how to do similar operations, but none that I could find exactly asking something this simple. I am trying this in Node.js:

```
db.collection('ratings').update( { "refid":refid, "votes.ip":ip },
  {
    $push: { votes: { "ip":ip, "rating":rating }
  }
})
```

But it just keeps adding new entries when I vote from the same IP.

**NOTE:** I am not using Mongoose.

I apologize if my question is overly elementary, I'm pretty new to MongoDB. I'm just wondering if there's a good way to do this baked in rather than iterating through every record in "votes" programmatically. Thanks!

**EDIT:** What I'm asking isn't currently possible, I've marked an answer below correct which contains the explanation and a link to a ticket at MongoDB for an enhancement.

As for the scenario in my question here, the code below works for me. I have no idea how good or bad it is performance wise, but it covers all of these scenarios:

- If the record doesn't exist at all, create it
- If the record exists, look for the IP and if found, update the rating
- If the record exists but the IP does not, insert a new rating

Works:

```
db.collection('ratings').findOne({ "refid":refid }).then(function(vote) {  
  if (vote == null) {
    newrating = {refid: refid, votes: [{ ip: ip, rating: rating }]};
    db.collection('ratings').save(newrating);
  } else {
    db.collection('ratings').findOne({ "refid":refid, "votes.ip":ip }).then(function(rate) {
      if (rate != null) {
        db.collection('ratings').update(
          { refid: refid, "votes.ip" : ip },
          { $set: { "votes.$.rating" : rating } }
        )
      } else {
        db.collection('ratings').update({"refid":refid,"votes.ip" : {$ne : ip }},
          { $push: { votes: { "ip" : ip, "rating" : rating, }}}
        )
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527980/can-you-specify-a-key-for-addtoset-in-mongo

Comment: As far as I can see, both the link and the subsequent question in the comments don't cover my scenario; only how to prevent an update based on key, and separately, how to add a record if the key is not present. It doesn't cover the scenario of: if present update else add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert a document if not exist is done by upsert and if you want to update a conditional embedded document you need $ positional operator. So you need to use both in query to implement above functionality.

**But right now mongodb don't support upserting with $ positional operator**

> Do not use the positional operator $ with upsert operations because,
> inserts will use the $ as a field name in the inserted document.

**So what you want is not possible to do it in one query for now, alternatively you can do it in two queries.**

First

```
db.collection('ratings').update(
  {"refid":refid, "votes.ip": ip},
  {
     $set: { "votes.$.rating":rating }
  }
)
```

It returns the number of documents updated, if it is 1 it's fine, and if it is 0 you need to push new record.

```
db.collection('ratings').update( { "refid":refid, "votes.ip":{$ne: ip}},
    {$push: { votes: { "ip":ip , "rating":rating  }}
})
```

There also jira ticket for positional operator and upserting, plz vote for this issue if you want this functionality in mongodb. Below is the link of issue

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3326

(**EDIT**: The jira ticket was closed with *Won't Do* in June 2019)

Comment: Thanks. Puneet, I am going to edit the original post with the code that worked best for me, but mark yours as the correct answer because it's a precise explanation why it's not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.collection('ratings')).update( { "refid":refid, "votes.ip":ip , "votes.rating":{$ne: rating }},
    {$push: { votes: { "ip":ip , "rating":rating  }}
})
```

it'll add new record if rating is not existent for given ip, and if record is exist for given ip and rating then no duplicate record added.

Answer (score 0):

It might be solved this way as well. This is the one I used for my work.

Pull out the matching value and push the new value as below:

```
db.collection(‘ratings’).update({“refid”:refid},
         {$pull: {votes: {“ip": ip}}},
    {multi: true});

db.collection("ratings").update({“refid":refid},
     {$push:{‘votes’:{"ip":ip,"rating":rating}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the refid exists, this code should do the work

```
let bulk = await db.collection('ratings').initializeOrderedBulkOp();

//edit if exist
await bulk.find({ refid: refid, 'votes.ip': ip })
          .updateOne({ $set: {'votes.$.rating': rating} });
//add if doesn't exist
await bulk.find({ refid: refid, 'votes.ip': {'$ne': ip} })
          .updateOne({ $push: {votes: {ip: ip, rating: rating}} });

await bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe

```
db.collection('ratings').update( { "refid":refid, "ip":ip },
   {
      $addToSet: { votes: { "ip":ip, "rating":rating }
   }
})
```