# I Want add if data in element array not exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this data in database.

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ef287370ff5dc3d6fda7b"),
   "name" : "Jhones Crows",
   "hobbies" : [ 
      {
        "name" : "swim",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ef287370ff5dc3d6fda7b")
      }, 
      {
        "name" : "run",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ef287370ff5dc3d6fda7c")
      }
   ]
}
```

And I try to add data into hobbies if data in hobbies not exist. I try this :

```
db.getCollection('milo').update(
{'_id' : ObjectId("5a6ef287370ff5dc3d6fda7b"), 'hobbies.name' : 'sport'},
{ $addToSet : { 'hobbies' : {
    'name' : 'sport',
}}
},
{upsert : true}
)
```

And I want data result like this :

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ef287370ff5dc3d6fda7b"),
   "name" : "Jhones Crows",
   "hobbies" : [ 
      {
        "name" : "swim",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ef287370ff5dc3d6fda7b")
      }, 
      {
        "name" : "run",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ef287370ff5dc3d6fda7c")
      },
      {
        "name" : "sport",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ef287370ff5dc3d6fda7a")
      }
   ]
}
```

so suppose the value of sport is not in hoobies.name. will add a new name object in the hobbies. but if there is not change anything

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('milo').update(
{'_id' : ObjectId("5a6ef287370ff5dc3d6fda7b"), 'hobbies.name' : {$ne:'sport'}},
{ $addToSet : { 'hobbies' : {
    'name' : 'sport',
}}
},
{upsert : true}
)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you specify a key for $addToSet in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527980/can-you-specify-a-key-for-addtoset-in-mongo)

Comment: This works very great .  I don't know that there is $ne in mongodb.

Comment: thank you Veeram. you are very helpful