# Create a document local index over a array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I have the following structure in my Mongo document:

```
{ 
  property1: 'value',
  property2: 'value',
  items: [
    {
        name: 'name1'
    },
    {
        name: 'name2'
    },
  ]
}
```

Is possible to define a local index over the items array?
In my case, `item.name` was a unique key but only in this document.
Other documents can have also a `item` with the same `name` that a `item` in other document (but the `name` in a `document` cannot be repeated).

Now I'm checking manually if the name is already in use before add/update elements in the `document.items` array, but if Mongo is capable to do it I will prefer...

EDIT: I have tried to create a index over `items.name` but if I create that index Mongo doesn't allows to insert/update a item if the `name` is already defined in other `document`.

Comment: Unique index only works at the document level. If you want mongodb to do this for you then create a separate collection  and create indices over there.

Comment: Appreciate your fast reply, but note than items are not only a array of values but a structured array. I have read about "$addtoset" before, but I think "$addtoset" is not supporting structured arrays. Please, can you remove the "duplicate" flag due to isn't a duplicated question?

Comment: Please check the second [Can you specify a key for $addToSet in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527980/can-you-specify-a-key-for-addtoset-in-mongo). It will show you how `$addToSet` works with **array of objects**.