# mongodb, check if the key exist while appending to an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

Note: checking if the key `books` exist or not, creating if not and than updating it.

I am using mongodb driver with nodejs.

In the `db.collection('userData')`The document looks like this:

```
{ 
    user_id: 'user1',
    books: [{
               id: 'book1',
               title: 'this is book1'
    },
            {
               id: 'book1',
               title: 'this is book1'
    }]
}
```

when inserting a new book entry, how to check if the array of `books` exists in the document, if not then add a key `books` in the document and then insert the book entry.

Comment: i have to check if the key 'books' exist or not ?

Comment: this is different,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527980/can-you-specify-a-key-for-addtoset-in-mongo ,

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/ ```db.scores.find(
   { results: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 80, $lt: 85 } } }
)``` searches in array of elements. Maybe works with upsert command too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do 2 separate queries,

- Find user document
- Check condition if books field present
- If Present then push object, else set new field

```
var user_id = "user1";
var bookData = { id: 'book1', title: 'this is book1' };

// FIND USER DATA
var userData = await db.collection('userData').findOne({ user_id: user_id }, { books: 1 });

var updateBody = { $push: { books: bookData } };
// IF BOOKS FIELD NOT PRESENT THEN SET NEW
if (!userData.books) {
  updateBody = { $set: { books: [bookData] } };
}

var updateData = await db.collection('userData').updateOne({ user_id: user_id }, updateBody);

console.log(updateData);
```

---

Second option you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$ifNull` check is field is null then return []
- `$concatArrays` to concat current `books` with new book object

```
var bookData = { id: 'book1', title: 'this is book1' };
db.collection('userData').update({
    // put your condition
  },
  [{
    $set: {
      books: {
        $concatArrays: [
          { $ifNull: ["$books", []] },
          [bookData]
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Py-FwwGh4U)