# addToSet mongoDB not adding if one value is repeated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, crud

I have the following collection in MongoDB

```
[
  {
    "acronym": "front",
    "references": [
      {
        "date": "2020-03-04",
        "value": "5.6"
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-03-05",
        "value": "6.3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to use the function `$addToSet` in order to add new document into `references`. I know that it can be done with the following code:

```
db.collection.update({
  "acronym": "front"
},
{
  $addToSet: {
    "references": {
      "date": "2020-03-06",
      "value": "6"
    }
  }
})
```

And it will add the new document to the array `references`, so the result is the following:

```
[
  {
    "acronym": "front",
    "references": [
      {
        "date": "2020-03-04",
        "value": "5.6"
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-03-05",
        "value": "6.3"
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-03-06",
        "value": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

QUESTION: **What I want to obtain is that in the case of adding a `date` that is already in the array, the update will no be produced.**

Here is the playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/DPER2RuROEs

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add another qualifier to the update to prevent duplicated dates

```
db.collection.update({
  "acronym": "front",
  "references.date": {
    $ne: "2020-03-04"
  }
},
{
  $addToSet: {
    "references": {
      "date": "2020-03-04",
      "value": "6"
    }
  }
})
```

I got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527980/can-you-specify-a-key-for-addtoset-in-mongo)

Comment: Yah, but that will not check all the `references.date` that exist..