# Arrayfilter equivalent in mongodb update aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following data structure :

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f9a"
    },
    "name": "test",
    "managerid": {
      "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f99"
    },
    "teachers": [],
    "employees": [
      {
        "employeeid": {
          "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f99"
        },
        "firstname": "jean",
        "lastname": "charles",
        "tag": 4595,
        "status": 1
      }
    ],
    "groups": [
      {
        "groupid": {
          "$oid": "6295fa2191ae50ba47e9d25c"
        },
        "groupname": "mongroupe",
        "employees": [],
        "permissions": []
      },
      {
        "groupid": {
          "$oid": "6295fa2191ae50ba47e9d25d"
        },
        "groupname": "mygroup",
        "employees": [],
        "permissions": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to add employee objects to one group. The objective is to get to something like this :

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f9a"
    },
    "name": "test",
    "managerid": {
      "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f99"
    },
    "teachers": [],
    "employees": [
      {
        "employeeid": {
          "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f99"
        },
        "firstname": "jean",
        "lastname": "charles",
        "tag": 4595,
        "status": 1
      }
    ],
    "groups": [
      {
        "groupid": {
          "$oid": "6295fa2191ae50ba47e9d25c"
        },
        "groupname": "mongroupe",
        "employees": [
          {
            "employeeid": {
              "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f99"
            },
            "firstname": "jean",
            "lastname": "charles"
          }
        ],
        "permissions": []
      },
      {
        "groupid": {
          "$oid": "6295fa2191ae50ba47e9d25d"
        },
        "groupname": "mygroup",
        "employees": [],
        "permissions": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So that the employee is also embedded in the group object. This would be pretty easy with the following code (basing myself on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65112446/16686765) :

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f9a",
  },
  "groups.groupid": {
    "$oid": "6295fa2191ae50ba47e9d25c"
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "groups.$.employees": {
      "$concatArrays": [
        "$groups.employees",
        {
          "$filter": {
            "input": [
              {
                "employeeid": {
                  "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f99"
                }
              }
            ],
            "cond": {
              "$not": {
                "$in": [
                  "$$this.employeeid",
                  "$groups.$.employees.employeeid"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

BUT the thing is aggregation pipelines can't work with positional operators `field.$.otherfield`, neither with arrayfilters.

As a consequence I can't select the right group (`"groups.groupid": {"$oid": "6295fa2191ae50ba47e9d25c"}` filter)

Anybody know what to do ? I'm pretty new to aggregation pipelines... Here's the related playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Kgftb2oBpV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the followings with aggregation pipeline:

1. `$match` with your criteria
2. `$unwind` at `groups` level
3. `$addFields` and process the logic with `$filter`
4. `$group` to reform the unwinded result
5. `$merge` to perform the update back to the collection

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f9a"
      },
      "groups.groupid": {
        "$oid": "6295fa2191ae50ba47e9d25c"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$groups",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "groups.employees": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              "$groups.groupid",
              ObjectId("6295fa2191ae50ba47e9d25c")
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$groups.employees",
              "initialValue": [
                {
                  "employeeid": {
                    "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f99"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "in": {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    "$in": [
                      "$$this.employeeid",
                      "$$value.employeeid"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": "$$value",
                  "else": {
                    "$concatArrays": [
                      "$$value",
                      [
                        "$$this"
                      ]
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "else": "$groups.employees"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      employees: {
        $first: "$employees"
      },
      groups: {
        $push: "$groups"
      },
      "managerid": {
        $first: "$managerid"
      },
      "name": {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      "teachers": {
        $first: "$teachers"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wd9BT6b_Ybf) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks but your example only works if there is only one group in the array. When you add more groups, you realize the employees get added to all of them which is not what i want. Look : https://mongoplayground.net/p/nJ3srypDCkT

Comment: @rrrrr sorry my bad. updated the answer to perform the groupid checking with a `$cond`

Comment: Yes perfect it works ! Aggregation pipelines seem very tricky tho... Do you know any good resource to learn how to use them ? :)

Comment: @rrrrr Stackoverflow is generally not a suitable place to seek recommendations for books, tools, software libraries etc. But typically when you google out the behaviour you want to achieve, you will be redirected to some StackOverflow answers that might help